# Connect lists to object within DispForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-designer, connected-web-parts, display-form

I am creating a page where users can see information for a chosen customer. On the same page I would also like to show To-Do's and Events filtered by that customer. As seen in the picture, I've added To Do-list and Eventslist as web parts within the DispForm.aspx as well as a bunch of sample data. However, I am unable to connect the lists to the customer.

Any idea how that connection could be made? Sadly I have neither InfoPath nor Visual Studio, I'm stuck with SharePoint Designer. That limits one's code possibilites a lot.

[image]

Edit: I cannot create the connections as between "normal webparts"; when trying, I receive "No Provider Schema". I tried also to make the connections in SP Designer, but as shown in the picture below (sorry it's in Swedish) the columns are empty and I cannot continue from there.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by connecting the web parts. For example edit the To DO List webpart and click on Connections -> Get Filter Values From. Here Select the Customer list. Then in Provider field name, select the column (in this case it will be Name) whose value will be used for filtration. Similarly select the Consumer filed (Customer) which will be used for filtration. Click on Finish.
Repeat same steps for Events list.

Answer (score 1):

For this task You need to use Webpart Connections. Edit Page on DispForm.aspx, Then click on Your Customer Part, select web part connection-> Provide Values. In my example I created list with users, and List called Notes, which have user name in "Responsable". Next see screenshots:

[image]

Then set options of target webpart, where You want to catch this value:

[image]

and in the end select what field will be associated with what in target webpart(Name will be associated with 'Responsible'):

[image]

As a result You get connected web part, filtered by Your customer:

[image]

That's all. You don't need Designer or Visual Studio for that, Sharepoint can do it Out-of-Box.

Comment: Thanks, that is how its done usually. Unfortunately this time it does not work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This does NOT work any more, when the provider of the Row is a Data Form Webpart instead of a list view webpart.
It used to work in former times, but I also didn't find a workaround yet. Error msg after chosing "Get filter values from" is always "No provider schema"